# Fibonacci Memoization in Python

Tags: python, fibonacci, memoization

I wrote this code to calculate the nth Fibonacci number and it works (calculates the right number) but fails because the table doesn't get updated.  Anybody know why?

```
# memoization
n = 12
table = np.ones(n+1)*-1
def fib3(n):
    if table[n]==-1:
        if n<=2:
            table[n] = 1
        else:
            table[n] = fib3(n-1)+fib3(n-2)
    #return table ##This was part of my original solution but I removed it because it wasn't working
fib3(12)
```

This is the error I get that I think is caused by a non-updating table (since table[n] always = -1):

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: You're not actually returning anything from your function.

Comment: Your function does not `return` anything. So `fib3(n-1) + fib3(n-2)` makes no sense, because you're summing 2 void values.

Comment: aka `table[n] = None + None`

Comment: you need to return table[n]

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I thought table was a global since it is declared outside the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed returning the value for fib3 function

```
import numpy as np

# memoization
n = 12
table = np.ones(n+1)*-1
def fib3(n):
    if table[n]==-1:
        if n<=2: 
            table[n] = 1
        else:
            table[n] = fib3(n-1)+fib3(n-2)
    return table[n]
fib3(12)

144
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't explicitly returning anything, and so your `fib3` function automatically returns `None`. Thus your line `table[n] = fib3(n-1) + fib3(n-2)` evaluates to `table[n] = None + None` and there is no `+` operator defined for `None`.

Comment: `None` is a singleton, no plural.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 technically correct, which is the best kind of correct! Will update. Also voted to close because it's essentially a typo.

Comment: This is the comment that most helped me understand the issue. Thanks.